# Differentiation, logarithmic fucntion

Tags: calculus, logarithms, differential-algebra

The Derivative of $\log_{10} x$ with respect to $x^2$ is?
The Answer is having loge(base10)

Comment: So you mean 
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \log_{10} (x) = \frac{d^2}{dx^2} \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(10)} = -\frac{1}{\ln(10) x^2} = -\frac{1}{\frac{\log_{10}(10)}{\log_{10}(e)} x^2} = -\frac{\log_{10}(e)}{x^2}
$$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let y= $\log_{10}x=\frac{\ln x}{\ln 10} $ via Change of base

and $t=x^2$

Now $$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{x \ln 10}*\frac{1}{2x}$$